# React - setState keeps causing multiple re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm generating a random number that links to an icon in an array.

```
 const icons = [paperIcon, scissorsIcon, rockIcon];

// Selected a random icon
const randomIcon = Math.floor(Math.random() * icons.length);

console.log(randomIcon);
```

The console.log produces one result between 0 and 2. Perfect, awesome, exactly what I need it to do.

From there I'm trying to set the state of the icon chosen.

```
 setComputerIcon(icons[randomIcon].icon);
```

This causes the randomIcon function to happen multiple times, anywhere from twice to 10+ times as well as this warning:

```
Cannot update a component (`PickedIcons`) while rendering a different component (`ComputerPick`).
```

PickedIcons is just a component that shows both the player's icon and the computer's icon. ComputerPick is the component all this is going on in.

So I throw it into a useEffect:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        setComputerIcon(icons[randomIcon].icon);
    }, []);
```

The warning goes away but now the randomIcon function is being called twice generating two numbers (strict mode is off). So I change the dependency to include randomIcon:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        setComputerIcon(icons[randomIcon].icon);
    }, [randomIcon]);
```

And now I'm back to calling randomIcon anywhere from twice to ten times.

There's something I'm missing that's causing this useEffect to call randomIcon twice when I only need it called once but I have no idea what.

Comment: just move the `const randomIcon = Math.floor(Math.random() * icons.length);` into the useEffect and leave the deps array empty, have you tried that?

Comment: Well I did and it didn't work, but I closed the server and reopened it and now it does so, there we go.